# NDK template instantiion cannot compile operator <<

Tags: android-ndk

I'm using operator << on a custom class. This compiles fine in VS2017 but not in NDK.

```
static std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const V & v2) { return os << V.x; }
```

In NDK, it goes through its list of template specialization in basic_ostream and can't find it.

```
 D:/Library/android-ndk-r16/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\ostream:1036:10: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__ndk1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >' and 'const cocos2d::Vec2')
  __os << __x;

 D:/Library/android-ndk-r16/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\ostream:218:20: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const V' to 'const void *' for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &
  basic_ostream& operator<<(const void* __p);
                 ^
 D:/Library/android-ndk-r16/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\ostream:755:1: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const V' to 'char' for 2nd argument operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, char __cn)

  D:/Library/android-ndk-r16/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\ostream:788:1: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const V' to 'char' for 2nd argument operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __os, char __c)
```

.  etc

Comment: What is `V`? There's not enough information here to know what went wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: V is a custom class


        class V
        {
           public:
               float x;
        }

Comment: Ever found a solution? Getting similar issues.

Comment: I don't think so, I've stopped android dev in c++